# Concurrent connections with a single AndroidHttpClient instance

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

In my project, I need to perform multiple HTTP requests with a single AndroidHttpClient instance but actually, HTTP requests are processed one by one. There is a way to define a maximum number of concurrent connections?

Comment: HTTP requests are not processed one by one. Are you using AsyncTask? Those are processed serially by default.

Comment: Yes I do, my AndroidHttpClient instance is static in a AsyncTask class which I extend in different RequestAsyncTask to perform requests with a single client. What can I do to have concurrent connections? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok sure. I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: OK sorry I was driving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requests are executed in parallel, but if you are using `AsyncTask` then the tasks themselves are by default executed serially, one at a time. To change this behavior, use `executeOnExecutor` method to run them in parallel:

```
new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ...);
```

That should resolve this problem.

Comment: I love you! Thank you very much! Just a question: There is no way for api < 11?

Comment: Interesting question but note that from API level 4 (DONUT) up to 11, the async tasks are executed in parallel by default, so you dont need to call this function on those API levels. You would only need to worry about pre-DONUT, and I doubt you need to support that.